# Error at Command Line:3 Column:195 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma 00917. 00000 - "missing comma" *Cause: *Action:

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert the values into my table as below:

```
insert into mdb_orders (patient_dbid, visit_dbid, order_dbid, filler_entity_id, order_status, study_instance_uid) 
values (224, -1, 108, acc_201, 'TM', 1.2.840.113704.7.1.0.18023822620616531.1704351258.3)
```

I do not know what is the problem. I tried running this in SQL Developer.

It says that I am missing a comma.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the string(`VARCHAR`/`VARCHAR2`) value into single quotes as follows:

```
INSERT INTO MDB_ORDERS (
    PATIENT_DBID,
    VISIT_DBID,
    ORDER_DBID,
    FILLER_ENTITY_ID,
    ORDER_STATUS,
    STUDY_INSTANCE_UID
) VALUES (
    224,
    - 1,
    108,
    'acc_201',
    'TM',
    '1.2.840.113704.7.1.0.18023822620616531. 1704351258.3'
);
```